# Array wont update when i JSON.stringify it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have this code below that is able to transfer the array value to another array when i click on it. For Example, when i click on `lime` it will move into my `Green Array` The problem is after i `JSON.stringify` my `Green Array` it doesn't show the updated value.

So this is the **before** i add in a value my `green array` has `5 values`.

[image]

And this is **after** I add in a value to my **`green array`** as you can see after I move the value in my array count increases but I don't know why when i `stringify` the array, it doesn't have the value I added in already I want to `stringify` it because I want to send the updated data to a **server**. Is there any reason why this is happening ?

[image]

```js
var red = {};
var green = {};
var random = {};
var fruits = [];

var fruits1 = {["fruit"]:"Apple", ["type"]:"1"}
var fruits2 = {["fruit"]:"Tomato", ["type"]:"1"}
var fruits3 = {["fruit"]:"Lime", ["type"]:"2"}
var fruits4 = {["fruit"]:"Guava", ["type"]:"2"}

fruits.push(fruits1,fruits2,fruits3,fruits4);

var randomFruits = fruits.filter(x => x.fruit).map(x => x.fruit);

var key = "Red Fruits";
red[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry','Pomegranate','Rassberry'];

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
green[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado','Lime','Honeydew'];

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
random[key3] = randomFruits;

 function redraw() {
     var combineString = '';
     $.each(red[key], function(index) {
         combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + red[key][index] + '</div>');
     });
     $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

     $.each(green[key2], function(index) {
         combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv greenpill class">' + green[key2][index] + '</div>');
     });
     $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

     var randomString = '';
     $.each(random[key3], function(index) {
         randomString += ('<div class="pilldiv randompill class">' + random[key3][index] + '</div>');
     });
     $('.randomclass').html(randomString);
 }
 
 
 function listener() {
  
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#randomid div", function() {
            data = this.innerHTML;
   k1 = Object.keys(random).find(k => random[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
            index = random[k1].indexOf(data);
            random[k1].splice(index, 1);
            for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
             if (fruits[i].fruit === data) {
               if (fruits[i].type === "1") {
                 red[key].push(data);
                } else {
                 green[key2].push(data);
                }
              }
            }
            $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + green[key2].length);
            var element = $(this).detach();
            $('#combineid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
          });
      });
   
    $('body').on('click', 'div.new-green-fruit', function() {
        data2 = this.innerHTML;
        for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
         if (fruits[i].fruit === data2) {
           if (fruits[i].type === "1") {
             k2 = Object.keys(red).find(k => red[k].indexOf(data2) >= 0);
              index2 = red[k2].indexOf(data2);
              red[k2].splice(index2, 1);
            } else {
             k2 = Object.keys(green).find(k => green[k].indexOf(data2) >= 0);
              index2 = green[k2].indexOf(data2);
              green[k2].splice(index2, 1);
            } 
          }
        }
        random[key3].push(data2);
        $(this).detach();
        var element2 = $(this).detach();
        $('#randomid').prepend('<div class="pilldiv randompill class" >' + element2.html() + '</div>');
    });
 }
 redraw();
 listener();
 
 var testing = JSON.stringify(green);
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 2px;
}
.randompill:after{
    content: "\002B";
    float: left;
 width:16px;
}
.new-green-fruit:after{
    content: "\292B";
    float: left;
 width:16px;
}
.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor:default;
}
.greenpill {
  background-color: SpringGreen;
    cursor:default;

}
.randompill {
  background-color: LightBlue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
 .class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.top {
 margin-bottom: 20px
}
h3{
font-weight: normal;
}
.panel {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
 background-color:white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.new-green-fruit{
background-color: LightBlue;
cursor:pointer;
}
.top{
margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
</head>

<body>
        <div class="panel">
        <div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
            <h3 class="class center">Total Fruits</h3>
            <div id="combineid" class="combineclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
        </div>

        <div style="float:right;width:calc(50% - 5px)">
            <h3 class="class center">Random Fruits</h3>
            <div id="randomid" class="randomclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what issue you're having. You *seem* to be claiming that if you have an array, stringify it, it works fine the first time. When you modify that array, stringify it again, it does not show the modification? I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if only the relevant code was shown, and if you can pare it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. I mean, if you have an array and stringify it, it's pretty much going to be the string version of that array, so you're either (a) neglecting to re-stringify it, or (b) not operating on the array you think you are.

Comment: @DaveNewton As you can see in the 2nd picture when i `console.log(green)` it shows me the updated `array` but when i console.log my `testing` variable it doesn't show me the updated version. i stringify the `green array` at the bottom of my code i think it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: @DaveNewton Or does it actually works already just that i cant print it out on my browser's console??

Comment: ... `testing` is set when you stringify it. Subsequent changes to `green` have absolutely nothing to do with the value in `testing`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ohh ok so my logic was completely wrong do you have any suggestion on how to send this updated data to a server?

Comment: Stringify it after you change it?

Comment: Also, no offense, may I suggest google, blog posts, courses - you seem to be unclear about what stringification does/is and how it works, that's pretty basic. It's like me playing the violin without knowing how to place my left hand fingers properly.

Comment: @DaveNewton Am i not doing that in my current codes?

Comment: Uhmm... what was the thread all about up to this point? You obviously don't or you would not have posted your question. "JSON" is a *static string*. Once it's been created it's just there, a snapshot in time of the data structure you encoded. into this JSON string. It's like taking a photo, but the world keeps moving and your photo remains (static).

Comment: @Bobby I added answer, Hope it will help you understand the mistake you are doing in your code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine as expected. Look into the code base properly may be you are missing something.

```js
var greenFruits = ["Watermelon", "Durian", "Avacado", "Lime", "Honeydew"];

console.log("Green Fruits Object : ", greenFruits);

console.log("Green Fruits String : ", JSON.stringify(greenFruits));

greenFruits.push("Guava");

console.log("Green Fruits Object : ", greenFruits);

console.log("Green Fruits String : ", JSON.stringify(greenFruits));
```